# View VRML file with WebGL-capable browser

Tags: webgl, vrml

I have a legacy application that generates VRML 1.0 files. I'd like to build a WebGL-based web interface that can display these VRML files. Is there an easy way to do so?

Edit: Specified that they are VRML 1.0.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to convert the VRML into some format that one of the various WebGL scenegraphs, like O3D, sceneJS etc support natively. COLLADA looks like a good choice, since most of WebGL scenegraphs/renderers support COLLADA. Scour the web for some way to convert VRML to COLLADA, or write you own.

Comment: I have published a (slightly crude) VRML1.0 to VRML97 converter in JavaScript using (a slightly extended version) of the Wings 3D importer logic, at https://www.npmjs.com/package/vrml1to97

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can get it to VRML 2.0 (VRML '97) using a tool like the above-referenced one from Parallelgraphics, you can use the Fraunhofer Institute's tools (see discussion and links to InstantReality at http://www.x3dom.org/?page_id=532) to go from VRML 2 to either X3DOM or X3D.  With Firefox or Chrome and a current graphics card and driver, you've got the WebGL support needed to run X3DOM.  X3DOM handles only a subset of X3D, but can be referenced straight from XHTML and CSS, or plug-ins required.  It's at a much higher level and easier to deal with than dealing directly with WebGL.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it, X3D is a development from VRML, and there's a WebGL-based renderer for it called [X3DOM](http://www.x3dom.org/).  Converting over is unlikely to be zero-effort, but it might be easier than trying to make the jump all the way to a "native" WebGL format.

Answer (score 2):

VRML can be pretty complex with lots of interactivity and it doesn't look like a ont-to-one converter is available. However, here is what you could try:

1. Convert your VRML file to a standard OBJ file using something like [MeshConv](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~min/meshconv/)
2. Import the converted file in [CopperLicht](http://www.ambiera.com/copperlicht/index.html) (Free) or [CopperCube](http://www.ambiera.com/coppercube/index.html) (Not free)

You will then have some kind of conversion of your VRML file which you can fine-tune.

Comment: Unfortunately, MeshConv only supports VRML 2.0 as input files, and my files are VRML 1.0.

Comment: Parallelgraphics has a VRML1 to VRML 2.0 converter: http://www.parallelgraphics.com/products/converter97/ or some more tools there: http://www.interocitors.com/polyhedra/vr1tovr2/index.html