# VRML in Web browser

Tags: 3d, vrml

I want to build in 3d object (or animation) in the web site.
I have VRML (*.wrl) file and want to make it play in most browsers. Maybe i have to use flash, maybe html5, maybe some other tools... Is it possible to make 3d animation play in most of the browsers without any additional plugins ?

Comment: Have a look here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927250/view-vrml-file-with-webgl-capable-browser

Comment: You can use the [X_ITE javascript-WebGL](http://create3000.de/x_ite/getting-started/#embedding-x-ite-within-a-web-page) library to display a legacy VRML project in modern browsers. The X3D Consortium still views VRML as another 'flavour' of 3D on the web, as a subset of X3D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way today to have 3D in most web browsers in use today without a plug-in.  The most widespread support today would be to use Adobe Shockwave as many would have the necessary Adobe Flash plug-in already installed.  However I don't believe it runs out of the box on linux machines.

The future may lie in X3DOM (http://www.x3dom.org/).  It uses WebGL to allow a subset of X3D capability right in the browser with no plug-ins.  However, at present, a relatively current graphics card and drivers are required to run WebGL with Firefox and Chrome, and Microsoft has announced it has no plans to support WebGL in Internet Explorer.  However support for X3DOM using the Adobe Flash plug-in will address this.