# VRML plugin for Firefox on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, firefox, ubuntu, vrml

I would like to know if there is a way to render .wrl (vrml files) in Firefox running on Linux x86 ?
I've found some softs to open .wrl files (like orbisnap) but that's not embedded in the browser.
Thanks.

Comment: You may want to ask this on askubuntu.com or unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: [OpenVRML](http://openvrml.org/) has a plugin for Firefox.  Talk about a blast from the past!

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927250/view-vrml-file-with-webgl-capable-browser) has some useful information. Firefox in Linux (assuming you have recent graphics drivers and supported hardware) has a 3D rendering API called WebGL. With a bit of fiddling you can convert your VRML file into a format that can be rendered using WebGL and X3DOM without the need for an external plugin.